# Jaeger with Go Application only shows one span

Tags: go, jaeger, jaeger-client-go

I am currently trying to integrate Jaeger into my application. This works to the point that all metrics are sent to Jaeger and plotted there as well. The only thing that doesn't work properly is the rendering of calls from one service to another. So each call is currently displayed as its own trace.

My expectation is that I see a trace where the client calls service 1 who then calls service 2.

My thought was that I have to transfer some header with the same ID. But couldn't find anything more specific on this.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You don't need to transfer some header, you need to apply instrumentation to your RPC boundaries, which most likely already exists in the OTEL project for whichever framework you're using, you just need to install/enable it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) I'm using Jaeger Tracing Middleware from here:
https://echo.labstack.com/middleware/jaegertracing/
Maybe it has something to do with the NoopTracer. I'll take a look at that.

Comment: I would not recommend using this instrumentation (https://github.com/labstack/echo-contrib/blob/master/jaegertracing/jaegertracing.go). It relies on  jaeger-client-go, which is deprecated  & not maintained anymore. You are better off using OpenTelemetry in the long run.